# Search in a Set

Tags: python

I want to search for an element in set in Python. 
How can i get the index of the being searched element in fastest time?

`element in set` doesn't give index! i want to know index of the element.

Comment: elements in a set don't **have** an index!

Answer (score 8):

Use `lists` or `tuples` if you're interested in index, `sets` doesn't maintain any order.

From the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

> Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or
>   order of insertion. Accordingly, sets do not support indexing,
>   slicing, or other sequence-like behavior.

Or may be something like this:

```
In [1]: se=set("foobarspampython")

In [2]: se
Out[2]: set(['a', 'b', 'f', 'h', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'y'])

In [3]: list(se).index("f")    # in the original string the index is 0,
                               # but list(set) returns something different
Out[3]: 2
```

**Python 3.x:**

You can use `OrderedDict()` in python 3.x, and use your items as the keys of the dict.
`dict.keys()` returns `keysView` in python 3.x which is kind of similar to `sets`, and you can perform all the set operation on it.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict as od
>>> strs="foobarspampython"
>>> dic=od((x,"") for x in strs)

>>> dic.keys()                      #order is maintained

KeysView(OrderedDict([('f', ''), ('o', ''), ('b', ''), ('a', ''), ('r', ''),
                      ('s', ''), ('p', ''), ('m', ''), ('y', ''), ('t', ''),
                      ('h', ''), ('n', '')]))

>>> list(dic.keys()).index("f")
0
>>> list(dic.keys()).index("b")
2

>>> dic.keys() & {'a','b','c'}    # even set operations work fine on it
{'a', 'b'}
```

Comment: and the index is completely random in what you're showing!

Comment: @SilentGhost yes it's completely unpredictable what the order going to be.

Comment: @SilentGhost I think in python 3.x `OrderedDict` can be used. Using the items as keys with empty values. As `dict.keys()` returns a `keysView().`on which we can perform set operations.

Comment: `OrderedDict` was back-ported to python2.7

Comment: @SilentGhost but `dict.keys()` return a list in python 2.7, so we can't perform set operations on it.

Comment: set operations is not a requirement. Besides there are equivalent methods that support iterables.

Answer (score 2):

If you need both the ability to access the index and fast lookups, you should have a look at the (non-standard) [blist package](http://stutzbachenterprises.com/blist/). It provides a fast list implementation which maintains order and thus allows fast access. It won't be as fast as a `set` can be, but you will be able to retrieve indicies.